# ggplot custom category legend for shapefile

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, r-sf

```
  library(raster)
  library(ggplot2)
  library(sf)

  fr.shp.admin <- getData('GADM', country='FRA', level=0)
  fr.shp <- getData('GADM', country='FRA', level=1)
  fr.shp.df <- data.frame(fr.shp)

  set.seed(123)

  dat <- data.frame(
      NAME_1 = rep(fr.shp.df$NAME_1, 2), 
      season = rep(c('a','b'), each = 13),
      value = c(sample(0:6, size = 8, replace = T), 0.1, 0.6, 100, 500,1250,
                sample(0:6, size = 8, replace = T), 0.3, 0.7,50, 400,1700))

  fr.shp.sf <- st_as_sf(fr.shp)
  fr.shp.admin.sf <- st_as_sf(fr.shp.admin)

  temp.shp <- merge(fr.shp.sf, dat, by = 'NAME_1')

  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = temp.shp, aes(fill = value), colour = NA) +
  geom_sf(data = fr.shp.admin.sf, fill = NA, col = 'black') +
  facet_wrap(~season)
```

[image]

I want to plot this map such that instead of a continuous legend I have categories and I can define colours for those categories. For e.g.

```
  (0-1] # => 0 & < 1
  (1-2] # >= 1 & < 2
  (2-3] # >= 2 & < 3
  (3-4] # >= 3 & < 4
  (4-5] # >= 4 & < 5
  > 5   # >= 5
```

I want to do this so that I can colour distincvely each category. How can I do this in ggplot

Comment: Try `scale_colour_steps()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest a combination of `base::cut()` to turn your continuous variable into factor, and `ggplot2::scale_fill_manual()` to give the catergories named colours.

Consider this slight variation on your code:

```
library(raster)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)

fr.shp.admin <- getData('GADM', country='FRA', level=0)
fr.shp <- getData('GADM', country='FRA', level=1)
fr.shp.df <- data.frame(fr.shp)

set.seed(123)

dat <- data.frame(
  NAME_1 = rep(fr.shp.df$NAME_1, 2), 
  season = rep(c('a','b'), each = 13),
  value = c(sample(0:6, size = 8, replace = T), 0.1, 0.6, 100, 500, 1250,
            sample(0:6, size = 8, replace = T), 0.3, 0.7,50, 400, 1700))

fr.shp.sf <- st_as_sf(fr.shp)
fr.shp.admin.sf <- st_as_sf(fr.shp.admin)

temp.shp <- merge(fr.shp.sf, dat, by = 'NAME_1')

temp.shp$value2 = cut(temp.shp$value,
                      breaks = c(-Inf, 0, 1000, +Inf),
                      labels = c("low", "medium", "high"))

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = temp.shp, aes(fill = value2), colour = NA) +
  geom_sf(data = fr.shp.admin.sf, fill = NA, col = 'black') +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("low" = "cornflowerblue",
                               "medium" = "goldenrod2",
                               "high" = "red")) + 
  facet_wrap(~season)
```

[image]